# Get Uploaded File's Original Name

Tags: symfony

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
print_r($request->files);die;
```

gives me

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag Object
(
    [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
                        (
                            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
                            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
                            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
                            [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 879394
                            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
                            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpmUl54W
                            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpmUl54W
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'm trying to get at the value for 'originalname' i.e "Chrysanthemum.jpg" without resorting to a loop, but I can't seem to find the right syntax

Using the 1UP file uploader, but I dont think that's important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wound up working for me, I guess the OneUp Class handles it a bit differently

```
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
class UploadListener
{
     public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $original_filename = $request->files->get('blueimp')->getClientOriginalName();
     }
}
```

Relevent Frontend

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="blueimp" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('images') }}" multiple />
```

Answer (score 22):

When you upload files you get `UploadFile` ([API link](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html)) objects (basically the wrappers of array).

```
$this->getRequest()->files[0]->getClientOriginalName();
```

Can't try this now but you might need to do this instead:

```
$this->getRequest()->files['name_of_file_field_in_post']->getClientOriginalName();
```

where you would replace `name_of_file_field_in_post` with your form field's name.

Comment: Thanks for tjhe response, I get this error
FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag as array in /pathtofile/MediaBundle/EventListener/UploadListener.php line 41

The name I have on my input is "files[]"

Comment: Maybe this helps someone:

Files is not an array, it's a parameters bag (FileBag in this case). It has to be iterated over, like `foreach($request->files as $file)` then you can do the `getClientOriginalName()`.

Answer (score 18):

2015 Update:

```
$request->files->get('your-file-name')->getClientOriginalName();
```

`your-file-name` for me was just `file`.

This will probably help too:
https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/issues/21

Comment: Spot on. Thanks mate. (y)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using symfony 4,

I wanted to get the files original name. What worked for me is:

```
$form = $this->createForm(SomeType::class, $object);

if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $fileName = $object->getImage()->getClientOriginalName();

}
```

In my case getImage() is the getter for the name of the file upload field. So that would change to your relevant getter function for the file upload field.