# Get Original Name of a file

Tags: symfony, oneupuploaderbundle

I have a problem to get the orginal name of a file uploaded byoneupuploaderbundle

If i use

```
$this->getRequest()->files[0]->getClientOriginalName();
```

(See this post [Get Uploaded File's Original Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202595/get-uploaded-files-original-name) )
I have this error :

> FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot use object of
>   type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag as array in
>   /home/.../UploadListener.php
>   line 17

but i think is correct, see the var_dump :

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
var_dump($request->files);
```

give :

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag)#11 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["file"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#12 (7) {
        ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
        bool(false)
        ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
        string(22) "silk_icons_preview.png"
        ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
        string(9) "image/png"
        ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
        int(116463)
        ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
        int(0)
        ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
        string(14) "/tmp/php3GUXwQ"
        ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
        string(9) "php3GUXwQ"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: $request->files this is not an array like your var_dump told : Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag

Answer (score 2):

You have to do that :

```
$this->getRequest()->files->get('file')->getClientOriginalName();
```

The `'file'` value is the name of your file input.

Answer (score 0):

My function :

```
 public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event) {
      $test = $event->getRequest()->files->get('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
      var_dump($test);
    }
```

My form :

```
<form action="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" class="dropzone" name="upload" type="file" method="post" id="doc"></form>
```

Do :

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function
>   getClientOriginalName() on a non-object in
>   /home/www/.../UploadListener.php line 19