# Laravel 5.4 upload original file name and extention

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

how can i upload original filename (file.jpg) to database when submitting file via form. Controller:

```
public function addCv(Request $request){
        $cv = Cv::create($request->all());
        $file = $request->file_name;
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::putFileAs('public/uploads', $file, $filename);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

at the moment, this function uploads a path like this C:\xampp\tmp\php18DD.tmp.
Instead of that i want just filename and extension (file.extension).

Storage is working fine - storing with original name.

Answer (score 11):

You could try

```
$file = $request->image->getClientOriginalName(); //Get Image Name

$extension = $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();  //Get Image Extension

$fileName = $file.'.'.$extension;  //Concatenate both to get FileName (eg: file.jpg)
```

Comment: getClientOriginalName() will include file extension as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag in the view, from where you are uploading the file:

`<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below,

```
$this->getRequest()->files['name_of_file_field_in_post']->getClientOriginalName();
```

Reference: [Get Uploaded File's Original Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202595/get-uploaded-files-original-name)